# cannot toggle visibility of usercontrol in side td

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a usercontrol which I inset in to the page with the following code:

```
<table id="MainFrame" runat="server"  style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0px 3px 3px 3px;table-layout :fixed; width :562px; text-align :center; background-color :White;" cellpadding ="0" cellspacing ="0"> 
    <tr>
        <td style="width:5px;"><div style="width:5px;height:10px"></div></td>
        <td>
            &nbsp; 
            <div runat="server" id="divTextLink" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                 &nbsp;<Ligdol:TextLink ID="TextLink1" runat="server" Visible="False" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

In the code-behind I have an if statment which sets the visibility to true.
I put a breakpoint on the line and it's hit, but the visibility does not change.
I tried adding `&nbsp;` to the td, but that doesn't help either.
If I put the control outside of the table, everything works as it should.

**Edit:**  The usercontrol code

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TextLinks.ascx.cs" Inherits="NewChannels_Controls_TextLinks" %>
<img style="float: right;" src="/Ligdol/Upload/textlinks.png" />
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="txtLink"></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Do you have some styling that is affecting the display of the table? Could you post more of your table code?

Comment: Edited the post - added the table tag code

Comment: What if you add `<tr><td>FOOBAR</td></tr>` to the table? will that display?

Comment: Yes. I added it to the same cell as the usercontrol and it's shown, but not the usercontrol. I'm updating the post with the usercontrol code, in case it could be relevant.

Comment: the `div` that wraps it is a server control also. Is this being hidden in the code?

Comment: That was just for my testing. I removed the runat tag and that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<td>
    &nbsp; 
    <div runat="server" id="divTextLink" style="padding-top: 10px;">
         &nbsp;<Ligdol:TextLink ID="TextLink1" runat="server" Visible="False" />
    </div>
</td>
```

to this

```
<td style="padding-top: 10px;">
     <Ligdol:TextLink ID="TextLink1" runat="server" Visible="False" />
</td>
```

I can't see no other reason to this not work.